# Dapr golang Docker Compose - running into a ""errorCode":"ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE","message":"invoke API is not ready" error

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dapr

I am trying out Dapr for the first time ....refering to the Dapr go sdk at https://github.com/dapr/go-sdk...

... trying to host a Dapr service using golang with Docker Compose on my Windows 10 machine - using VSCode - and running into an issue connecting to ther service.

I have the docker compose file set to do a simple configuration as follows.  And trying to connect to the service via the Dapr API using curl

> golang service (taskapi service) => Dapr SideCar (taskapidapr)

I based it off of the example from https://github.com/dapr/go-sdk/blob/main/example/Makefile, but using Docker Compose.

When I try to connect connect to the service using

> curl -d "ping" -H "Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
> "http://localhost:8300/v1.0/invoke/taskapi/method/echo"

I am running into the following error.

> {"errorCode":"ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE","message":"invoke API is not ready"}

And the Dapr logs in Docker show a 'no mDNS apps to refresh.' - not sure if this is the cause of it and how to handle it.

Anyone can point me to what I am missing - greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

- Athadu

**golang package**

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/dapr/go-sdk/service/common"
    daprd "github.com/dapr/go-sdk/service/http"
)

func main() {

    port := "8085"
    address := fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port)

    log.Printf("Creating New service at %v port", address)
    log.Println()

    // create a Dapr service (e.g. ":8080", "0.0.0.0:8080", "10.1.1.1:8080" )
    s := daprd.NewService(address)

    // add a service to service invocation handler
    if err := s.AddServiceInvocationHandler("/echo", echoHandler); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error adding invocation handler: %v", err)
    }

    if err := s.Start(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        log.Fatalf("error listenning: %v", err)
    }
}

func echoHandler(ctx context.Context, in *common.InvocationEvent) (out *common.Content, err error) {
    if in == nil {
        err = errors.New("invocation parameter required")
        return
    }
    log.Printf(
        "echo - ContentType:%s, Verb:%s, QueryString:%s, %s",
        in.ContentType, in.Verb, in.QueryString, in.Data,
    )
    out = &common.Content{
        Data:        in.Data,
        ContentType: in.ContentType,
        DataTypeURL: in.DataTypeURL,
    }
    return
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
    taskapi:
        image: golang:1.16
        volumes:
            - ..:/go/src/lekha
        working_dir: /go/src/lekha/uploader
        command: go run main.go
        ports: 
            - "8085:8085"
        environment:
            aaa: 80
            my: I am THE variable value
        networks:
            - lekha
    taskapidapr:
        image: "daprio/daprd:edge"
        command: [
            "./daprd",
            "-app-id", "taskapi",
            "-app-protocol", "http",
            "-app-port", "8085",
            "-dapr-http-port", "8300",
            "-placement-host-address", "placement:50006",
            "-log-level", "debug",
            "-components-path", "/components"
        ]
        volumes:
            - "../dapr-components/:/components" # Mount our components folder for the dapr runtime to use
        depends_on:
            - taskapi
        ports: 
           - "8300:8300"
        networks:
           - lekha
        #network_mode: "service:taskapi" # Attach the task-api-dapr service to the task-api network namespace
    ############################
    # Dapr placement service
    ############################
    placement:
        image: "daprio/dapr"
        command: ["./placement", "-port", "50006"]
        ports:
            - "50006:50006"
        networks:
            - lekha
networks:
    lekha:
```

[image: Docker Container List]

[image: Inspecting the network in Docker shows the containers to be in the same network]

**Daprd shows these mDNS messages in logs - not sure if this is the cause**

> time="2021-05-24T01:06:13.6629303Z" level=debug msg="Refreshing all
> mDNS addresses." app_id=taskapi instance=442e04c9e8a6
> scope=dapr.contrib type=log ver=edge
>
> time="2021-05-24T01:06:13.6630421Z" level=debug msg="no mDNS apps to
> refresh." app_id=taskapi instance=442e04c9e8a6 scope=dapr.contrib

**Additionally, I see the containers on the expected ports ... running fine in Docker desktop...**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, were you able to find a solution for it?

Comment: I'm getting the same . I can't do service to service invocation. Dapr state is working though.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y742t.png)

```
{
"errorCode": "ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE",
"message": "invoke API is not ready"
```

}

same as yours

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).